# C# delegate syntax issue

Tags: c#

The code I have so far is:

```
private void MyThreadRoutine()
{
    this.Invoke(this.showProgressGifDelegate);
    ModifyConnectString.main();
    this.Invoke(this.HideProgressGifDelegate);
}



public void showProgressGifDelegate() { pictureBox2.Visible = true; }
public void HideProgressGifDelegate() { pictureBox2.Visible = false; }
```

From what I can tell this should work but non the less it does not compile because I get the error

> 'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate''
>   and 'The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, params
>   object[])' has some invalid arguments'

Any ideas on the correct syntax for my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your code in a [`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to convert your `delegate` to an instance of `Delegate`:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.showProgressGifDelegate));
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.HideProgressGifDelegate));
```

Comment: Thanks will accept as answer shortly.

Comment: No hurry. Will be here tomorrow too ;) . Glad I could help. See also the possible duplicate question, it has some other useful tips.